# Reading Eicha without understanding, Vs. reading Megilas Esther without understanding it

Tags: halacha, tisha-bav, lamentations-eicha

See [THIS ARTICLE](http://revach.net/halacha/tshuvos/Rav-Moshe-Shternbuch-Do-Women-Need-To-Hear-Eicha/606)

> Rav Moshe Shternbuch: Do Women Need To Hear Eicha?
>
> Reading Eicha is a major part of the aveilus of Tisha B'Av.  Rav Moshe
>   Shternbuch says (2:250) that since women are Chayav in all the
>   halachos of aveilus of Tisha B'Av, they are also required to hear
>   Eicha. If they can not go to Shul they can say it sitting on the floor
>   in the privacy of their own home.
>
> Since reading Eicha is part of the mitzva of mourning the Bais
>   HaMikdash it is important for both men and women to understand the
>   general meaning of Eicha. **If you just read it without any
>   understanding you haven't accomplished the goal.** Rav Shternbuch
>   recommends to use a readily available translation. **A woman who doesn't
>   understand anything at all and does not have access to a translation,
>   need not go through the motions of reading Eicha**.

See [Gemara Megilla 18a:](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.18a.23-24?lang=bi)

It says there in explanation of why one reads Megillas Esther even if he does not understand the Hebrew language at all:

> הכא נמי מצות קריאה ופרסומי ניסא: - "We fulfill the mitzva of reading
>   the Megilla and publicizing the miracle of Purim by reading these
>   words as they appear in the original text. "One who speaks a foreign
>   language who hears the Megilla being read in Hebrew fulfills the
>   mitzva of reading the Megilla and publicizing the Purim miracle even
>   if he does not understand the words themselves.

Question:

Why does reading Eicha differ from reading *Megillas Esther* which one must read even if he does not understand the Hebrew language, because it is considered "as publicizing the Purim miracle even if he does not understand the words themselves", likewise, why shouldn't it be considered lamenting and mourning the destruction of the Bais Hamikdash even if one doesn't understand the words, (as long as one knows that that is the theme of what is being read)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no takana to read Eicha, there is just a minhag in order of being sad about the destruction of Jerusalem, so there is no interest if one does not understand it.

Where reading Megilat Esther is an obligation per se, even if the reason is Pirssoume Nissa, that is "just" the reason, but after the takana, that does not change if he understand or not, as the obligation is just to read it.

Answer (score 0):

The rashi on pirsumei nissa
says if the person doesn’t understand they will ask others
who will explain and that is good for pirsum which is the ultimate goal of kris’s megilla

eicha is not about pirsumm it’s about aveiluss and kinna which we
do in public
chazal did not want anyone needing to go around and ask questions that’s not what tisha bag is about